# UIPopoverController, how to change the size of it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I've got **UIPopoverController** in my Split-View application, I just need to make popover longer. 
In viewDidLoad of DetatilViewController I put:

```
self.popoverController.popoverContentSize=CGSizeMake(320, 1400);
```

Nothing happens( when should I put this? thanks

Done with that ^^^ How can I set background for Popover? thaanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From iOS 7:

```
popoverView.contentViewController.preferredContentSize =  CGSizeMake(320, 1400);
```

Comment: put that in view will appear)

Answer (score 14):

Set `contentSizeForViewInPopover` property of `UIPopOverController`

Comment: This was deprecated and removed. Use `preferredContentSize` instead.

Answer (score 11):

```
popView.contentViewController.preferredContentSize = Your Size
```

This works on iOS 8 but will crash or have no effect on lesser versions

Hope the answer :)

Comment: contentSizeForViewInPopover stopped working after updating to ios 8, and preferredContentSize is working for ios 8.

Answer (score 6):

Try overriding `-(CGSize)contentSizeForViewInPopover` in your view controller, and return the size you want your view controller to be.

Comment: NOTE: this is deprecated in IOS7.

Comment: If it's deprecated, what should we do instead?

Comment: @Jenny "Use UIViewController.preferredContentSize instead."

Answer (score 4):

if u want to set the content size of the `UIPopoverController` try this,

```
self.popNameList =   [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:search_table];
self.popNameList.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 100);
```

good luck..